# XML to String Conversion in .NET

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

```xml
<IS_ID>
     <PROPERTIES SOURCE="Correction" USER="123@xyz.com" DATE="14-Sep-2012 15:47:27" />
     <HEADER Action='Update' />
     <HEADER EMO_ID="12503652" />
     <HEADER SourceResolutionID="JT-362" />
     <DETAIL Type=Cumulative/Service Pack/Patch Release />
     <DETAIL Language=English />
     <DETAIL ServicePack="11" />
     <DETAIL ExternalDefectID=FIN-17243 />
     <DETAIL ResolutionID=JT_1239 />
     <DETAIL Classification=M3 Applications />
 </IS_ID>
```

I can convert the properties into `String` using the code below, but the same doesn't work for `HEADER` and `DETAIL` elements, as they have closing tag for each attribute. How can I resolve this issue?

```vb
Dim sbProperties As New System.Text.StringBuilder
sbProperties.Append("<PROPERTIES>")
If Not xmlAttributes Is Nothing Then
    For Each xmlAttribute In xmlAttributes
        sbProperties.Append("<" & xmlAttribute.Name.ToUpper & ">" & xmlAttribute.Value & "</" & xmlAttribute.Name.ToUpper & ">")
    Next
    sbProperties.Append("</PROPERTIES>")
    Dim strProperties As String = sbProperties.ToString
End If
```

Comment: That's not valid XML to start with... (and if you're trying to *build* XML, you definitely should *not* be doing it with string operations - use an XML API).

Comment: I am looping through the nodes and creating String for each of the Elements . I would like to pass the string for each of those created Elements to the database and update tables .

Comment: Properties have all attributes closed in one tag but for header & details I need a different loop . Please help

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you sample "XML" is invalid. However, you should be using one the XML parsing classes such as `XMLReader` combined with a `StringBuilder`.

For information on how to do this using VB and C# you might find [this link helpful.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)